# Redirect to php page when modify any value from Multiple dropdown

Tags: javascript, php

I have 10 (or more ) dropdown list as below

```
echo '<select data-id="'.$id.'">';
echo '<option value=\"YES\">YES</option>';
echo '<option value=\"NO\">NO</option>';
echo '</select>';
```

When I change value for any of this dropdown It should navigate with other page(actions.php) with 2 values ( $id & dropdown selection value).

Please help me with your expertise

Thanks in advance

I'm not using html form, so I'm not sure how to trigger PHP page while modifying/change dropdown value

Answer (score 0):

This is not about PHP, it is about pretty trivial JS only:

```
<select data-id="1">
    <option>YES</option>
    <option>NO</option>
</select>
<select data-id="2">
    <option>YES</option>
    <option>NO</option>
</select>

<script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

        document.addEventListener('change', function( e ){

            window.location.assign(`/actions.php?id=${e.target.getAttribute('data-id')}&answer=${e.target.value}`);

        });

    })
</script>
```